# Delegate(common) click listener in Android

Tags: android, button, click, touch, listener

Lets say I have a few buttons and their click is handled by a common handler is there a way to define the listener once and not defining an `onClick` attribute for each button?

```
<Button android:onClick="handler" />
```

Perhaps parent delegation as in browsers or some interceptor .....imagine you have 50 buttons, you declare on click for each explicitly???

Comment: use onClick(View v) method

Comment: You can give the same click handler for all your buttons and then in onClick() method, just use switch case for various different operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I finally came to as solution it works only with `touchables` for instance `TextView` isn't a touchable:

In java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MainActivity activity = this;
    /* Any kind of ViewGroup that is 
       parent of the common listener views. In the example it is the rootView */
    View rootView = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

    // Buttons are touchables
    ArrayList<View> touchables = rootView.getTouchables();

    // Define the common on click listener for the buttons
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public final void onClick(View view) {
            activity.onBtnClick( (Button) view );
        }
    };

    // Iterate trough touchables and if the View is a button assign the listener
    for (View v: touchables) {
        // TODO: omit button if that common listener isn't meant for it
        if(v instanceof Button) {
            v.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
}

// The listener callback
protected final void onBtnClick(Button btn) {
    String btnStringId = btn.getResources().getResourceEntryName(btn.getId());
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    /* Any kind of ViewGroup that is 
       parent of the common listener views. In the example it is the rootView */
    val rootView = window.decorView.rootView
    val touchables = rootView.touchables
    val listener = View.OnClickListener {
        onBtnClick(it as Button)
    }
    touchables.forEach { if (it is Button) {
        it.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }}
}

protected fun onBtnClick(btn: Button) {
    var btnStringId = btn.getResources().getResourceEntryName(btn.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do so.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Button> buttons;
ViewGroup parentView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.cord);


    //Replace the above line with the container view i.e.
    //Replace  parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.cord);
    // With parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.<YOUR MAIN VIEW/PARENT CONTAINER>);
    //R.id.cord is R.id.<YOUR MAIN VIEW/PARENT CONTAINER> for me because my Relative Layout 
    // container's name is cord.


    for(int i=0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {

        childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
        //The if may change there are other options try them too.
        if(childView.getClass().getName().substring(35).equals("Button")){


            buttons.add((Button)parentView.getChildAt(i));
        }
        /*
        //Else part optional 
        //Remove comment to use
        else
            Log.e("Not","A Button");*/
    }

    for (int i =0;i<buttons.size();i++){
        buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Do the work here
                Log.d("Button Clicked",Integer.toString(view.getId()));
            }
        });
    }





    }
}
```

This is a way that you can solve your problem...

Comment: If you know how many buttons to use you can use array instead of List.

Answer (score 1):

The best way: Just let your activity implement `View.OnClickListener`, and write your `onClick` method like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // your code for button1 here
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // your code for button2 here
        break;
    // even more buttons here
    }
}
```

Then, in your XML layout file, you can set the click listeners directly using the attribute `android:onClick:`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1" />
```

Comment: But that's what I want to avoid declaring `onClick` for each button explicitly....

Comment: okay then, try a common onClickListener. And assign that listener to your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be achieved at the activity level programmatically. So no need to define the "onClick" attribute in XML.

You define a View.OnClickListener class. For e.g.

```
View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // here you can define different code for different buttons
         };
```

then you attach this listener to all your buttons on one place

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
```